the p-menu in p-splitButton doesn't show
i use primeng V13 to work with splitButton but the menu doesn't show
<p-splitButton
    appendTo="body"
    label="{{menu[0].label}}"
    icon="{{menu[0].icon}}"
    styleClass="p-button-sm"
    class="split-Button"
  >
    <p-menu #menuModel [popup]="true">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let el of menu; let i=index;">
        <p-menuItem
          [label]="el.label"
          [ngClass]="'text-' + el.color"
          icon="{{el.icon}}"
        ></p-menuItem>
      </ng-container>
    </p-menu>
  </p-splitButton>


the value of menu

  menu = [
{ id: "display", label: 'Afficher', icon: 'fa fa-eye', color: "primary", command: (ev) => { this.display.emit(ev); } },
{ id: "edit", label: 'Modifier', icon: 'cil-pen', color: "success", command: (ev) => { this.edit.emit(ev); } },
{ id: "delete", label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-times', color: "danger", command: (ev) => { this.delete.emit(ev); } },

];

DO you have any console error? and what is value of menu property?
Please check this for more info: https://primeng.org/splitbutton\

no i dont have any error. u can check the question i just add the value of menu. i already work with the example from primeng.org/splitbutton and it work but i want to use p-menu
